# Advice for storing dna sequence data in mysql

Tags: mysql, configuration, dna-sequence

I am creating a database that will store DNA sequence data, which are strings like this: 'atcgatcgatcg' and protein sequence data that are also strings like this: 'MKLPKRML'.

I am a beginner in MySQL management I want to ask you for the proper configuration of these columns in terms of data types, character set and collation. There will be around one million of DNA and protein sequence rows, and I want to use string comparisons as higher performance possible.

I've reading about this problem and I have these conclusions and doubts

1. I could use VARCHAR(MAX) because the length of my strings will not be higher than 65,535 characters.
2. BOLD fields commparisons are fasters. Is better than VARCHAR in this case? I am also thinking in issues associated with a retrieve of data because of the retrieve must be in string type, not bytes
3. Is better to use latin-1 instead of utf-8? I'am only storing alphabet without special characters

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What sort of comparisons would you be doing with the sequences?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, In the database there will be strings that are exactly the same in length and composition, In this case I need to extract a 'representative' sequence of the whole group and track down the sequences of this group with an identifier that will be in other column